# How do I turn off cellular data on certain apps with an iPhone 6

Tags: cellular-data

[image]

Many of my apps I barely use but still need use up some of my cellular data. I would like to turn the data of for certain apps, but as you can see in the picture it looks ,in a way, tinted. It won't let me turn off the data on the apps or turn it on for apps.

I don't know if I'm supposed to click a certain thing somewhere else in the settings.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

Check if restrictions is turned on in settings -> general -> restrictions. Turn it off and try again.

Comment: & make sure to switch on Find iPhone - that's the one you really need to work at any time, should you ever lose the phone.